# How to setup and configure aerospike cluster on cloud

Tags: aerospike

I have installed [aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/get-started/#/)  on 2 VMs of amazon cloud, I want to form a aerospike cluster with these 2 machines. Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check some recommendations for AWS on [this page](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/deploy_guides/aws/recommendations/), which has a link for the specific [configuration for mesh](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/network/heartbeat/#mesh-unicast-heartbeat) (as AWS does not support multicast).

Finally, if you are going to be accessing your cluster through the nodes public IPs, make sure you configure the [access-address](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#access-address) to the public IP but have the nodes mesh-see-address-port to be the nodes private IPs.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the instruction from the Aerospike website:

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/

It covers all major platforms and should take you less than 10 minutes to get up and running with first node.

Then install it on another machine, then add this additional node:

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/clustering.html